# Rectangle Touching in android

Tags: android, canvas

I create new Class called Rectangle , it contains below codes:

```
package com.example.komeil.speedcolor;

/**
 * Created by Komeil on 20/11/2016.
 */

public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    private int left;
    private int top;
    private int right;
    private int bottom;
public Rectangle(String name,int color,int left,int top,int right,int bottom)
{
    super(name,color);
    setLeft(left);
    setTop(top);
    setRight(right);
    setBottom(bottom);
}


public void setLeft(int left)
{
    this.left = left;
}

public int getLeft(){
    return left;
}

public int getTop()
{
    return top;
}

public void setTop(int top){
    this.top = top;
}

public void setRight(int right){
    this.right = right;
}

public int getRight(){
    return right;
}

public void setBottom(int bottom){
    this.bottom = bottom;
}

public int getBottom(){
    return bottom;
}
}
```

And i want create object from it and draw it with canvas.drawRect() like blow code:

```
canvas.drawRect(rectangle.getLeft(),rectangle.getTop(),rectangle.getRight(),rectangle.getBottom(),paint);
```

but when i use blow code for detect touch event on rectangle object it doesn't work:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gameThread.doOnTouch(event);
}


public boolean doOnTouch(MotionEvent event){

    synchronized (event){

        int eventAction = event.getAction();
        int xEvent = (int)event.getX();
        int yEvent = (int)event.getY();

        switch (eventAction){

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        if(xEvent >= rectangle.getLeft() && xEvent <= rectangle.getRight()
                                && yEvent >= rectangle.getBottom() && yEvent<= rectangle.getTop())
                        {
                            touched = true;
                            score +=5;
                        }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touched = false;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So how detect rectangle touch?

Comment: try to use TouchListener to your View.

Comment: how i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

change the yourCustomView to your viewName.

Please change accordingly

```
yourCustomView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            int x = event.getX();
            int y = event.getY();
            if(x > rectLeftX && x < rectRightX && y > rectBottomY && y < rectTopY){
                /* Trigger your action here */
            }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

check this , you will get some hints [Detect touch](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/09/detect-touch-and-draw-rect-on-bitmap.html)

Comment: @komeilshahmoradi , okay does the listener working ??

Comment: listener working well but if statment is wrong in doOnTouch

Comment: i wrote same as you right,whats differences between your if and my if?

Comment: @komeilshahmoradi x > rectLeftX && x < rectRightX && y > rectBottomY && y < rectTopY is not same